# iOS WatchOS5 how to customize title in GraphicRectangular complication?

Tags: ios12, apple-watch-complication, watchos-5

I want to remove text from my graphic rectangular complication, or set it to empty string. By default it is the app name. I tried to set display name to " " within watchKit plist file, but that did not seem to change it.

**How do I remove text from my graphic rectangular WatchOS5 complication?**

I see that there's some way to get (assign?) a CLKTextProvider  as described here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/clktextprovider However, it seems to involve adding a localizable strings file and I don't want to mess with this if there's an easier way to get image only for the `CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicRectangularLargeImage`

```
    func getLocalizableSampleTemplate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTemplate?) -> Void) {
        // This method will be called once per supported complication, and the results will be cached


        if complication.family == .graphicRectangular {
            let template =  GraphicTemplate()
            template.textProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider.init(text: "")
            handler(template)
        }else {
            handler(nil)
        }
    }


class GraphicTemplate: CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicRectangularLargeImage {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mess with localizable strings (phew).

There are two places you'll need to set up the appearance of the complication.

1. The sample template - this is displayed to the user as they're customizing a face and scrolling through the list of available complications. You provide this sample in the `getLocalizableSample(for: withHandler:)` method per family of complication, as you show in your question.
2. The actual live complication shown on the face, which you provide in the `getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void)` method of the `CLKComplicationDataSource`.

In both places you'll need to return the template with a text provider (you'll crash on runtime if not), although it's fine to return an empty string. This should remove the app name.

```
    let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicRectangularLargeImage()
    template.textProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider.init(text: "")
    template.imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: myImage)
    return template
```

(By the way, have you seen the recent [Apple Tech Talk about complications for watch os5](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/208/)? It's a good one ).